# Como descobrir a versão do Laravel instalada em meu projeto?

Tags: laravel, composer

Eu estava com a versão do **Laravel 4.2.7** instalado no meu computador.

Senti falta de dois métodos importantes no `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`, que é o `whereDoesntHave` e o `doesntHave`.

Ao executar um `composer update` ele atualizou para a versão **4.2.11**, e esses dois métodos enfim apareceram no `Builder` do `Eloquent`.

A partir desse problema, percebi a importância de saber qual é a versão do Laravel que eu estou trabalhando.

Como faço para saber a versão do Laravel que eu estou usando (procurei no código-fonte e não achei)?

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso via `Composer` ou tem algum arquivo no `Laravel 4` que guarda a versão atual (num comentário ou algo do tipo)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Se você rodar o comando `php artisan --version` no seu CLI ele vai mostrar a versão do seu Laravel.

Ou então você pode abrir o arquivo `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php`, você vai ver a versão da sua instalação no topo do arquivo, definido como uma constant:

```
/**
     * The Laravel framework version.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const VERSION = '4.0.11';
```

Adicionalmente, você pode por o código abaixo no final do seu `routes.php`, então você pode acessar `seudominio.com/laravel-version` e verificar sua versão:

```
Route::get('laravel-version', function() {
    $laravel = app();
    return "Your Laravel version is ".$laravel::VERSION;
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Você pode utilizar o Composer para isso também:

`composer show laravel/framework`

Nas primeiras linhas você pode conferir a versão instalada:

```
λ composer show laravel/framework
name     : laravel/framework
descrip. : The Laravel Framework.
keywords : framework, laravel
versions : * v5.1.31
```